# Extract all chains from a tree data structure

Tags: python, tree

I have a data dictionary like this:

```
dic = '{"data":"Harry", 
        "children":[{"data":"Bill",
                     "children":[]},
                    {"data":"Jane",
                     "children":[{"data":"Diane",
                                  "children":[]},
                                 {"data":"Mark",
                                  "children":[]}]
                    }
                   ]
       }'
```

I want to extract all the chains included in the tree hierarchy separately i.e. all the complete paths from the first node to every last node:

- Harry -> Bill
- Harry -> Jane -> Diana
- Harry -> Jane -> Mark

I extracted the tree edges from the dictionary using this code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import sys
from treelib import Node, Tree

data = '{"data":"Harry", "children":[{"data":"Bill","children":[]},{"data":"Jane","children":[{"data":"Diane","children":[]},{"data":"Mark","children":[]}]}]}'
data = json.loads(data)

# Extract tree edges from the dict
edges = []
tree = Tree()
added = set()

def get_edges(treedict, parent=None):
    name = treedict['data']
    added.add(name)

    if parent is not None:
        edges.append((parent, name))

    for item in treedict["children"]:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            get_edges(item, parent=name)

get_edges(data)

#Dump edge list in Graphviz DOT format
print('strict digraph tree {')
for row in edges:
    print('    {0} -> {1};'.format(*row))
print('}')
```

The tree edges list looks like this:

```
[(u'Harry', u'Bill'), (u'Harry', u'Jane'), (u'Jane', u'Diane'), (u'Jane', u'Mark')]
```

It can be used to print the tree.

Is there anyway to get the chains using the data dictionary or the tree edges list?

Comment: What are you asking exactly ? Could you define a "chain" ? Could you add the example of such structure ?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "algorithm tree path to leaf node", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  This is a standard meme in Data Structures.  A directory is a painful way to represent a tree.  Since you've already extracted the nodes and edges, I recommend a graph package, such as `networkx`.

Comment: By the way, unless you have some constraints, you should avoid using python 2 which will be deprecated in [a few month](https://pythonclock.org/). I say that because of the `from __future__ import print_function` and the unicode strings typical of Python 2

Comment: I'm defining a chain as a complete path from the first node to the leaf node. In my example there are 3 chains. I tried networkx (I even plotted the "tree") but it looks like there's no hierarchy between nodes. It's more like a neighbour relationship than a parent-child relationship. Maybe I'm wrong :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing one parent pass a tuple of parents:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import json
    import sys
    from treelib import Node, Tree

    data = '{"data":"Harry", "children":[{"data":"Bill","children":[]},{"data":"Jane","children":[{"data":"Diane","children":[]},{"data":"Mark","children":[]}]}]}'
    data = json.loads(data)

    # Extract tree edges from the dict
    edges = []
    tree = Tree()
    added = set()


    def get_edges(treedict, parent=()):
        name = treedict['data']
        added.add(name)

        if parent is not None and not treedict["children"]:
            edges.append((parent)+(name,))

        for item in treedict["children"]:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                get_edges(item, parent=parent + (name,))

    get_edges(data)

    #Dump edge list in Graphviz DOT format
    print('strict digraph tree {')
    for row in edges:
        print('-->'.join(row))
    print('}')
```

output:

```
strict digraph tree {
    Harry-->Bill
    Harry-->Jane-->Diane
    Harry-->Jane-->Mark
}
```

Comment: How can I discard the "intermediate paths"? i.e.: (Harry) and (Harry-->Jane). I only want to extra the complete path: from the first node to the leaf node: (Harry-->Bill), (Harry-->Jane-->Diane) and (Harry-->Jane-->Mark).

Comment: `if parent is not None and not treedict["children"]:` change the condition that add paths to add only last children, they have `treedict["children"]==[]`